# Seg Fault C++, list, list.last

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code crashes at insert function (segmentation fault), it looks like 'List.last' behave as static but its not. Dont mind the rest of a code. I know the solution must be simple but it cracks my head. It was a long time science I coded anything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

typedef int elementtype, position ;
const int maxlength=10;
struct List
{
    elementtype elements[maxlength];
      elementtype last;
};

position END(List l)
{ 
return(l.last+1);
}

position First(List l) 
{
if (l.last>=0)
return(l.last);
else
return(END(l));
}

position Next(position p,List l)
{
return(l.elements[p+1]);
}


position Previous(position p,List l) 
{
return(l.elements[p-1]);
}



position Locate(elementtype x, List l) 
{ int i;
for(i=0;i<=maxlength;i++)
{
if(x==l.elements[i])
return(i);
else 
return(END(l));
}
}

elementtype Retrieve(position p, List l) 
{
return(l.elements[p]);
}

bool Insert(int x, position p, List &l)
{
int i;

if(l.last-1==maxlength)
return(false);
else

if((p>=0)&&(p<=maxlength))
{l.last++;
for(i=l.last;i>p;i--)
l.elements[i+1]=l.elements[i];
l.elements[p]=x;
return(true);}
else return(false);

     }

bool Delete(position p, List &l)
{
int i;
if(p>0||p<l.last){
l.elements[i]=l.elements[i+1];
l.last=l.last-1;
return(true);}
else
if(p=l.last){
l.last=l.last-1;
return(true);}
else
return(false);

}

void print(List l)
{
    position i=First(l);
    while (i!=END(l))
    {
        cout<< Retrieve(i,l);
        i=Next(i,l);
    }
    cout<<("\n");

}



int main(){
List l;
l.last=-1;
Insert(100,First(l),l);
print (l);
cout<<l.elements[0];
for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
Insert(i,First(l),l);
print (l);

Insert (20,Previous(END(l),l) ,l);
print(l);
Delete( Locate(20,l),l);
print(l);
return 0;}
```

Comment: You tagged this as C++, but this is a very non-C++ approach. The only C++-specific thing you are using is `std::cout` :)

Comment: Too many flaws...both in the code as well as the coding style...

Answer (score 2):

Here in your `Locate` function

```
for(i=0;i<=maxlength;i++)
```

you have a problem as you are allowing access of index 10 in an array of length 10. Change to

```
for(i=0;i<maxlength;i++)
```

similarly here in `Insert`

```
if((p>=0)&&(p<=maxlength))
```

allows later access of index 10 at this line

```
l.elements[p]=x;
```

Currently you are accessing elements beyond the array limits. If an array is of size `x` you cannot access `array[x]` as indices are zero based.

Using a debugger would help you identify this.

Comment: are you sure it will make it work? Cause commenting `l.last++` in `Insert` makes it work and leaving it there or even incrementing it in main gives me seg. fault.

Comment: @user3086720 No I am not certain - the only way to be completely sure is to run it in a debugger - which is what you should do. I have merely highlighted a couple of instances where the limits of a loop variable allow access to an out of bounds element in your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the changes suggested by @mathematician1975 , one basic error is in the

`print(List)`
method.

When the statement `i=Next(i,l);` executes , it fetches a value from the `List.elements` array, which initially contains random values. So what comes in the variable `i` is a random index for the array which seems to be generating the segmentation fault.